# Working ANTLRworks2 on Linux

Tags: linux, antlr, antlrworks

I have downloaded what seems to be antlrworks2 from here http://tunnelvisionlabs.com/products/demo/antlrworks

But I cannot find how to run the resulting material.

The unpacked material consists of these directories
antlrworks2  bin  etc  ide  java  platform
and lots of sub directories with lot and lots of .jar files but I have no idea
what I need to run to get it operating.

Answer (score 1):

You should run **bin/antlrworks2** to launch the application.

Note that future releases of ANTLRWorks 2 (starting with release 2.2) will be distributed exclusively through the NetBeans Plugin Portal (and Update Center), which will simplify things significantly.